# «Искренний интерес и забота о других». Есть ли ошибки?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, типы-ошибок

Есть такое предложение:
**Искренний интерес и забота о других.**

Получается, что "интерес о других" и "искренний забота". Когда сдавал ЕГЭ, я знал, как это называется. Напомните, пожалуйста. И скажите, как правильно, если **так** неправильно?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка - **нарушение управления при однородных членах предложения.** Не хватает управляемого существительного после слова "интерес", требующего дательного падежа. Слово "забота" при этом управляет существительным в предложном падеже:

Интерес - к кому?, а забота - о ком?

Правильно: ***Искренний интерес к другим и забота о них.***

Если же Вам важно подчеркнуть, что и забота была искренней, тогда не возбраняется повторить определение:

***Искренний интерес к другим и искренняя забота о них.***

Comment: Возможно, так, скорее всего, это и подразумевалось. Но, в отсутствие контекста, можно предположить, что "интерес" не относится к "другим". Например: —Что характеризует его отношение к людям?  Искренний интерес (к людям) и забота о других (людях).

Comment: На мой взгляд, здесь всё прозрачно: подразумевается интерес к людям и забота о них. Очень распространённая ошибка при употреблении однородных членов - отсутствие необходимого дополнения в форме требуемого падежа после первого однородного элемента.